# Return an ArrayList in android with volley

Tags: android, arraylist, android-volley

I am trying to return arrayList to fill up a recyclerview, when i debug y stop in response everything goes god, but when i stop in return, arrayList is empty

This is my code:

```
public static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.38/yoap/api/v1.0/amymatch";

Context context;
ArrayList<MyMatch> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

MyMatch myMatch;

public MyMatchBackground(Context context) {

    this.context = context;

}

public ArrayList<MyMatch> getArrayList(final String token) {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("match");
                        int n = jsonArray.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String date = object.getString("date");
                            String time = object.getString("time");
                            String club = object.getString("club");
                            String level = object.getString("level");
                            myMatch = new MyMatch(date, time, club, level);
                            myMatch.setClubName(club);
                            myMatch.setDate(date);
                            myMatch.setTime(time);
                            myMatch.setLevel(level);
                            arrayList.add(myMatch);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap =  new HashMap<String, String>();

            hashMap.put("Accept", "application/json");
            hashMap.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);
            return hashMap;
        }
    };
MySingleton.getmInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonObjectRequest);


    return arrayList;
```

And arrayList dont have anything, and my response is thisone

```
{
"match": [
    {
        "date": "05/08/2017",
        "time": "8:15",
        "club": "sport center",
        "level": "Masculino C"
    },
    {
        "date": "01/09/2017",
        "time": "22:15",
        "club": "sport center",
        "level": "Masculino D"
    }
]
}
```

i see in debug mode array is geting correctly, but arraylist comes empty

someone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volley is asynchronous, so you are returning an empty list **before** Volley actually executes `onResponse`.

Therefore, you can't just "return an ArrayList" from a method that runs Volley.

You need to put `arrayList.add()` within `onResponse` **and** notify your RecyclerView adapter after the loop over the JSONArray.

You should also change that method to be void to not confuse yourself.

---

One pattern I recommend people follow is to use callbacks

```
public void getArrayList(final String token,
     MatchListAsyncResponse callback) {
             List<MyMatch> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                ... 
                arrayList.add(myMatch);
             } 
             if (null != callback) callback.processFinish(arrayList);
```

The general implementation of `MatchListAsyncResponse` can be taken from

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

```
public interface MatchListAsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(List<Match> matches);
}
```

Whether you use Volley or AsyncTask, the callback concept is the same. Use interfaces to pass back the data to where it was called.

Comment: How can I call getArrayList? How do I pass the callBack in?

Comment: @Matt Similar to how you add `View.OnClickListener` to a button. `getArrayList("token", new MatchListAsyncResponse() { ... });`